# Hermitian Matrix Determinant

Tags: linear-algebra, determinant

I have the following question to prove that $$\overline {( A)} = \overline{\det(A)}$$
The question does not state anything else, so I am not sure if A is Hermitian (this question is under the Hermitian section). I am not sure how to approach this but it doesn't seem to make sense to me because the left side would be a matrix while the right side would be a single number. Is this just a typo?

Comment: I should say that the question is $det\overline {( A)} = \overline {det(A)}.$

Comment: Thanks, was confused about this because dimensions aren't the same. Now I'm able to prove it :)